# Linker issue when updating C++/CLI project from VS2008 to VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, linker, c++-cli

We have a C++/CLI project currently in .NET 3.5 compiled using v90 (VS2008) compiler. Everything works fine. But when I change the project to .NET 4.0 with v10 compiler (VS2010), those linker error pops out:

> error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent
> layout information in duplicated types (tagTOUCHINPUT):
> (0x02000743). ...\MainWindow.obj
>
> error LNK2022: metadata
> operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in
> duplicated types (tagTOUCHINPUT): (0x0200072d). ...\stdafx.obj

The `tagTOUCHINPUT` structure seems to be part of MFC, which the project is heavily using.
I tried using `ildasm -tokens`, but it just crashes with empty error window.

I have no other ideas how to debug this project. Mainly because we inherited it and it is pretty old one. It is also pretty big, which means isolating the problem might be extremely hard.

Edit: After some work, I'm pretty sure I removed all references to native libraries from the project, except those automatically added by VS. The problem still exists.

Comment: It is a declaration in the Windows SDK, WinUser.h include file. I don't have old enough versions of the SDK installed anymore, but the ULONG_PTR member didn't used to have that type when 64-bit operating systems where not yet around.  Rebuild ancient libraries you link.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you think it is somehow possible to find out what library might need to be updated? We don't have any of our own (everything is built within the project itself), but it might be some 3rd party library.

Comment: Well, tackle the real problem.  There is never any point in having SDK structures like TOUCHINPUT appear in the metadata of a .NET assembly.  The kind of problem that's induced by having *way* too much code compiled with /clr in effect.

Answer (score 0):

Our solution have some old MFC based C++ libraries that was switched to /clr compilation for some reasons.
I got similar error messages when **ALL** projects in my solution was switched to /clr compilation. 
Errors **disappears** when the main project (.exe) was compiled without /clr flag.